# Error parsing parameter information in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am developing a report using the Pentaho Report Designer. One of the parameters is DeviceId with displaytype Dropdown.
The query corresponding to this parameter is:***select distinct DEVICE_ID as DeviceId from ${Categ}***

When I try to publish the report in pentaho user console, I get an error message saying - "Error parsing parameter information".

If I hard code the query as:***select distinct DEVICE_ID as DeviceId from dm_test***,it is working fine.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parametrize the table name. Parameters in PRD are not variables you can replace before the query is passed to the JDBC driver. They're passed to JDBC as query parameters, and table names cannot be used.

You can do what you're trying to achieve with a PDI datasource (Pentaho Data Integration), passing the table name as a transformation parameter and ticking the "Replace variables in script" checkbox in a Table Input step.